# How to optimize a script in terms of performance

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function called `ajaxCall()` which simple does the call on a server and returns a value from a feed.

What I wanted to do is to save the value from feed to `firstInterval` variable, wait 10 seconds, make the call again and save the value to `secondInterval` variable. And then animate the increasing of these numbers on the webpage. This is what we have so far:

```
 setInterval(function(){
   getAmounts() 
}, 11000);

function getAmounts(){
  firstInterval = ajaxCall();
  setTimeout(() => {
    secondInterval = ajaxCall();
    animateValue('#bronze-price p', firstInterval, secondInterval, 10000)
  }, 10000);
};

  function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    start = parseInt(start);
    end = parseInt(end);
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    var obj = document.querySelector(id);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}
```

So the idea is to have a function which gets first interval, after 10 seconds it grabs the second interval and calls the animation. This all is wrapped into setInterval function so I could change the number smoothly repeatedly.

However I am pretty sure that thats not a very clean solution since its `setInterval` in `setTimeout` and this all is wrapped in another `setInterval` function. I am also getting this kind of warnings in the console with both functions:

> [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took ms

**What would be the best approach to follow up on this idea but optimize the code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) makes this a lot easier to handle while also getting rid of `setTimeout/setInterval`. An example would be:

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values_inclusive
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// fake api endpoint
const ajaxCall = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 400, 1000 + getRandomIntInclusive(0, 1000));
});

// simple animation helper using requestAnimationFrame
const animate = (from, to, duration, cb) => {
    const start = performance.now();

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        requestAnimationFrame(function loop() {
            const f = (performance.now() - start) / duration;

            cb(from + Math.round(f * (to - from)));

            f < 1.0
                ? requestAnimationFrame(loop)
                : resolve();
        });
    });
};

// main
(async (interval) => {
    // where to output
    const dst = document.querySelector('#out');

    // initial value
    let prev  = 0;

    // wait for next value of ajaxCall
    while (true) {
        const next = await ajaxCall();

        console.log(`animating: ${prev} -> ${next}`);

        // animate from `prev` to `next`
        await animate(prev, next, interval, current => {
            dst.innerHTML = current;
        });

        prev = next;
    }
})(10000);
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: this is wonderful! Im gonna spend some time on it to understand it completely now but its working as charm. Thanks